# Dependency Inversion & Decoupling

Tags: design-patterns, concepts, dependency-management

I'm wondering if someone might explain the last paragraph written in this example on Dependency Inversion & Decoupling.

http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/core-concepts.html

Following the example code, understanding the reasoning behind decoupling classes by implementing a base class is fine.

What I would like some clarification on is the last paragraph:

> However, there is one problem with this implementation. We don’t have a main method. We > definitely need one in order to run our
>   application, and somewhere in this main method we will need to
>   instantiate the LocalVoteRecorder.
>
> By instantiating the LocalVoteRecorder in our main method, we would
>   break Rule #1 of Dependency Inversion. We have coded to the
>   abstraction, we have integrated our changes, but our application would
>   still have a dependency on a lower level class.

Does this mean it is not possible to create a truly decoupled application? How can it be that one could write a 100% decoupled application? Is it even necessary, and are there any best practices I could read up on.

Many thanks

Comment: You *can* write truly decoupled applications. The next sections in that tutorial present some techniques to realize the deeper decoupling.

Answer (score 4):

It is very hard (although in a language that has reflection not entirely impossible) to create a 100% decoupled application. With reflection, we can use this to allow the user to specify concrete classes for each object needed in the application at runtime (perhaps through a configuration file), thus achieving complete decoupling at the expense of increased complexity.

But a more important question to ask is why you would want to.

We try to decrease coupling in most of our code because coupling makes change harder, by causing a single change to have consequences for all of the code that is coupled to the module that was changed.

But if we group together all of the coupling in a single location, this problem is mitigated. A change to a module's behaviour may also require a change to the code that initialises the module, but because all such code is kept together no further changes propagate out of that initialisation code, so we don't experience the negative effects. This is good enough for almost all applications.

Comment: You don't need reflection, just [Structural typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system). Reflection is a pretty hacky way to do it, since you won't find out about screwed up dependency graphs until runtime *and* you pay some runtime overhead compared to figuring out everything statically, but it's probably the best you can do in a language with nominal typing.

Comment: @Doval  Even with structural typing you'll still need either a way of listing all types available or converting a string to a type reference of some kind, and then a way of using that type reference to create a new object. I would call such facilities reflection, although they may either have another name in some languages, or even be so integral to the language they need no specific name. Note that C++ code using templates is structurally typed, but does not provide facilities necessary for complete decoupling.

Comment: You don't need either thing. All you need is to ditch globally-unique identifiers as the means for one module to refer to another. Instead, you treat modules like first-class things that may be bound to names like just any other value, and modules that depend on other modules are essentially functions that take modules as arguments. If you need to create objects, you simply require that the module you depend on provide a function for it. The language can then check all the dependencies statically in the process of type-checking. That's the approach taken by Standard ML and Ocaml.

Answer (score 2):

Tight coupling is bad. Loose coupling is what need. And nothing works in complete Isolation, so dependency (to interface) is inevitable.

The best practices is to create decoupled components [as described here](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/core-concepts-dependency-injection-to-the-rescue.html) to avoid the disadvantages of tightly coupled application as mentioned on [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)). Consider below lines too as they metioned [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming):

> A module is closed if it has a well defined stable interface that all
>   other modules must use and that limits the interaction and potential
>   errors that can be introduced into one module by changes in another.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sort of.  You can't avoid the coupling altogether.  The best you can do is trade one kind of coupling for a generally more desirable kind.  Instead of two concrete objects coupled with each other, they are each coupled to an abstract interface.

Also, you have to depend on a concrete implementation at *some* point.  Just because those dependencies are not resolved until runtime doesn't mean they don't exist.  Sometimes the programmer doesn't care which concrete implementation is used, but usually they need a way to specify it somehow, which means a configuration file.

So, while you *can* have a program without any concrete dependencies at compile time, usually it's not worth it unless you have some specific need to substitute specific classes at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering if someone might explain the last paragraph:

The author says that having "Dependency Inversion & Decoupling" alone is not enought.

He means that "wiring the applicaton" by implementing a "main" method that constructs all classes is one option tu use the "independant modules"

In the next chapter he introduces, how to make "wiring the applicaton by code" a lot easier by introducing "Dependency Injection"

And later he introduces the spring-ioc that can do most of the wirining for you.

> Does this mean it is not possible to create a truly decoupled application?

**No** but a ioc like spring can make it a lot easier if you have understood the principles behind.